# Lodash.uniqueId always returns 1

Tags: javascript, npm, lodash

Try to use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#uniqueId) (version 4.17.11)

`_.uniqueId()` always returns ***1*** instead of random 3-digits number.

Also `_.uniqueId('prefix')` always returns ***prefix1***.

Is it a problem?

Comment: Have you tried calling it more than once?

Comment: Yes, every time the same result

Comment: "*instead of random 3-digits number*" wait, why should you get a *random* three digit number?

Comment: See documentation

Comment: It says it gives you a *unique* ID, not that it's a three digit one.

Comment: @AlexanderLadonin docs dont say anything about a random number

Comment: The documentation doesn't suggest that you should get a random three digit number. Those are just examples.

Comment: _.uniqueId('contact_'); // => 'contact_104'

Comment: [works for me](https://jsbin.com/naqivijuxe/2/edit?js,console) - getting unique numbers every time

Comment: @AlexanderLadonin It's not an idempotent function, they called it 103 times previously, OR they passed '10' as the prefix.

Comment: @AlexanderLadonin that's an example output. The documentation part says it's *unique*. Nothing about *random* or *three digit*

Comment: You are misinterpreting the documentation. Try to paste `console.log( _.uniqueId());console.log( _.uniqueId());console.log( _.uniqueId());` into their REPL so you see the results of calling it trice in succession in the same program.

Comment: i tried to call UniqueId in Express every time when 'npm start' and every time lodash droped ID

Comment: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/uniqueId.js This is how that function is coded. It's just an object containing the prefix as a property. If the property does not exist, it's created and set to 0. Then that property is increased by one and returned.

Comment: That's because every time you start the script again, all variable are reset, so the counter will start at 0 again. lodash will not magically save all data between seperate runs of the script.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/221/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

lodash _.uniqueId() gives you a unique ID thats it. It will never give you the same ID twice while executing your script (if you restart the script it can and will give you the same output) but there is no random number or no specified number of digits. Just try running it.

```
_.uniqueId() //1
_.uniqueId() //2
_.uniqueId() //3
```

Comment: Note that it **might** give you the same number twice if, for instance, you run the code in Node and you simply restart the server. Hence not really suitable for database indexing and similar.

Comment: @MilanVelebit yeah, it's only giving you a unique sequence. No way of keeping it unique between different instances of Lodash.

Comment: @MilanVelebit, yes, I called this function every time after restarting a server.

Comment: @AlexanderLadonin yes. If you call _.uniqueId() and then restart your server you will forver get 1 back. Thats expected behavior.

Comment: I thought that this function will work like PHP uniqid(). It's a pity.

Comment: @AlexanderLadonin no not at all. Try this instead https://www.npmjs.com/package/uniqid

Comment: You should also take a look at [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)

Comment: @GifCo, a separate module, oh. Thanks. Maybe it is a single solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you run a new stance, each time the counter basically would start from 1, and hence you might be getting 1 in your case.

You can use this library [uniqid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uniqid), which would give you a new randomly generated id each time.

```js
import uniqid from 'uniqid';

console.log(uniqid()); // -> 4n5pxq24kpiob12og9
console.log(uniqid(), uniqid()); // -> 4n5pxq24kriob12ogd, 4n5pxq24ksiob12ogl
```